# Problems: Incomplete implementation, local declaration of 'banner' hides instance variable, expected expression, missing @end

Tags: iphone, xcode

I'm very new to this so please excuse me for the easy to fix mistakes

.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <iAd/iAd.h>
@interface withadViewController : UIViewController <ADBannerViewDelegate>{

ADBannerView *banner;
BOOL bannerIsVisible;

IBOutlet UITextField *textField1;
IBOutlet UITextField *textField2;
IBOutlet UILabel *label1;
}
@property (nonatomic, assign)BOOL bannerIsVisible;
@property (nonatomic, retain)IBOutlet ADBannerView *banner;
-(IBAction)calculate;
-(IBAction)clear;
@end
```

.m (where all the problems are for an unknown reason)

```
#import "withadViewController.h"
@interface withadViewController ()                  HERE IT SAYS INCOMPLETE IMPLEMENTATION
@end
@implementation withadViewController
@synthesize banner;
@synthesize bannerIsVisible;
-(void) bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner {
if (!self.bannerIsVisible) {
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"animatedAdBannerOn" context:NULL];
    banner.frame = CGRectOffset(banner.frame, 0.0, 50.0); HERE SAYS LOCAL DECLARATION OF BANNER HIDES INSTANCE VARIABLE
    [UIView commitAnimations];
    self.bannerIsVisible = YES;
    }
}
-(void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)aBanner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error {
if (!self.bannerIsVisible) {
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"animatedAdBannerOff" context:NULL];
    banner.frame = CGRectOffset(banner.frame, 0.0, -320.0);
    [UIView commitAnimations];
    self.bannerIsVisible = NO;
}

 -(IBAction)calculate {                           HERE IT SAYS EXPECTED EXPRESSION

int x = ([textField1.text floatValue]);
int c = x*([textField2.text floatValue]);

label1.text = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%2d", c];
}
-(IBAction)clear {
textField1.text = @"";
textField2.text = @"";
label1.text = @"";{
}
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}  
@end                                                             HERE IT SAYS MISSING @END
```

This is all of the .h and the .m files

Answer (score 1):

You never close your method:

```
-(void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)aBanner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error
```

This is causing the compiler not to see methods you've implemented (incomplete implementation) not understand `@end` and expect an expression.

Your local variable is hiding your instance variable because both are named `banner`.  Similar to how the following code would hide the outer variable:

```
id var;
{
    id var;
}
```

You can avoid this by renaming your parameter to something like `aBanner`.

Comment: Wait so I have to do what?

Answer (score 1):

You didn't close your if statment:

```
- (void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)aBanner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error {
    if (!self.bannerIsVisible) {
        [UIView beginAnimations:@"animatedAdBannerOff" context:NULL];
        banner.frame = CGRectOffset(banner.frame, 0.0, -320.0);
        [UIView commitAnimations];
        self.bannerIsVisible = NO;
    } // <-- HERE
}
```

I suspect there are other similar errors around. Just go over it again, step by step.

Indenting your code and keeping it tidy goes a long way towards avoiding issues like this. :)